# Extract part of filename while looking for file using bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, find

Can this be simplified ??

```
find *.xml |  sed -n "s/\(^.*\)\.xml/\1/p"
```

The goal is to retrieve first part of xml files.
I just noticed there is a regex repetition in there and thought there must be a simplified version

Comment: `ls *.xml | cut -d. -f1` (or `ls *.xml | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev` if the name contains periods.)

Comment: @Anubis, see [why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: btw, `find *.xml` is (very, **very**) buggy in and of itself; unlike `find . -name '*.xml'`, it doesn't properly recurse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a simplified version. `find` is a specialized tool -- it doesn't implement arbitrary text-processing support.

A version focused on correctness would actually be even *more* verbose, looking something like:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  base=${filename%.xml}
  echo "Filename $filename without its extension is $base" # put your actual command here
done < <(find . -name '*.xml' -print0)
```

...using a NUL-delimited stream rather than a newline-delimited one (which is fault-prone because filenames can contain newlines), and using a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to do the trim only from trailing position.

Answer (score 0):

try following in awk and let me know if this helps.

```
awk 'prev && FNR==1{close(prev);print prev} FNR==1{prev=FILENAME;sub(/\..*/,"",prev);} END{print prev}' *.xml
```